# Div class row render differently on chrome and firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with `<div>`, as you can see :

firefox display:

[image: firefox display]

chrome display:

[image: chrome]

html structure :

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="from_area" class="form-control input-lg typeahead typeahead-area-tariff" id="from_area" placeholder="Origin" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="to_area" class="form-control input-lg typeahead typeahead-area-tariff" id="to_area" placeholder="Destination" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" name="weight" class="form-control input-lg" id="weight" placeholder="Weight" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">Kg</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" name="length" class="form-control input-lg" id="length" placeholder="Length" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">Cm</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" name="width" class="form-control input-lg" id="width" placeholder="Width" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">Cm</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" name="height" class="form-control input-lg" id="height" placeholder="Height" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">Cm</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" tabindex="7"><span class="fi flaticon-search"></span> Search </button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I am using `<div class="col-sm-4">` but when I see it on firefox, input text "Width" breaks to a new line. Please help :(

Comment: on which version?, on 49.05b its working fine.

Comment: Works fine for me as well any CSS changes to columns you made yourself? e.g. margins

Comment: i fixed it. I  added `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the third input text :)  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] Added `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the third input text.
[Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)